# How to use generic classes with a child class that uses a method with an argument hinted to the generic classes's TypeVar?

Tags: python, generics, pylance

```py
import typing as typ


T = typ.TypeVar("T", str, int)

class Foo(typ.Generic[T]):
    def method(self, q: T) -> T:
        return q


class Bar(Foo[str]):
    def method(self, q):
        return q.capitalize()
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot access member "capitalize" for type "int*"
```

I'm using vscode's basic type checker using pylance.

**How do you remove the error above?**

Answer (score 0):

capitalize() method returns only string(works for only a string).

While reproducing, I could observe the similar issue as yours:

```
a=Foo()
b=Bar()
print(a.method(1),b.method(1))
```

**Error:**
[image]

But I didn't observe any issue while passing a **string/character** to the method function in `Bar()` class. Your code would work fine if you remove the capitalize function while passing an integer. Or you could add a condition while returning `q` in `Bar()` class as follows:

```
return q if str(q).isdigit() else q.capitalize()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the problem is i've already explicitly stated that the function takes in a string using the class definition (`Bar(Foo[str])`)